# Change comments in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

How do I change the comments to look like /* */ instead of // in VS 2008?

Answer (score 1):

```
// this is a line comment, it will only comment this line
// for the next line you need to repeat //

/* this is a block comment

you can do all sort of stuff here

and you won't have to worry about beginning the line with some special chars

until the end*/
```

Since those two types of comments are a bit different I would say that you should both of them. It's not an error to have line and block comments in the same file.

I suppose you could run a regexp replace that will replace `//` on the beginning of the line with `/*` and add `*/` at the end but you will end up with something like this

```
/* first line comment */
/* second line comment */
/* third line comment */
/* forth line comment */
```